# Global irreducible admissible representations analogue

Tags: rt.representation-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, p-adic-groups

Let ${A}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ denote the adele over the rational numbers. Then it is known that cuspidal modular forms of level $N$ correspond to some unitary automorphic representation of $\operatorname{GL}_2({A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$.
My question is that are there some functions $f$ on upper half plane of the form
$$f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_ne^{2\pi inz}$$
satisfying suitable conditions  which correspond to an (irreducible) admissible (not necessarily automorphic) representations of $\operatorname{GL}_2({A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$. I have not been able to find anything about this in the literature. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: No, because "corresponding to functions on the upper half-plane" is precisely what makes automorphic representations automorphic.